# computed props in combination with usePage behave different between build and dev compiles / Laravel / VueJs3 / Interia / Vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite, inertiajs, laravel-10

I hope somebody can help.

Working with Laravel 10.x, Inertia and Vue JS, incl Vite. The code behaves different when I run dev or build mode with npm.

If you take this code:

```
// Tracker.vue

<script setup>

    import { Head, router, usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
    import { ref, reactive, computed } from 'vue'
    //*** more imports ***/

    const page = usePage();
    const user = computed(() => page.props.auth.user);

    [...]

    function anyFunction()
    {
        // this.user.interval works running npm run dev, but not npm run build
        console.log(this.user.interval) // works with npm run dev, but not npm run build
        console.log(user.value.interval) // works on both, dev and build
        return true
    }

    // REST OF CODE ... not relevant
```

my vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        minify: true //for debug vite build change to false
    }
});
```

and my package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.0.0",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.5",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.8.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.18",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.41"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.0.11",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.3.4",
        "vue3-colorpicker": "^2.2.2"
    }
}
```

Is this expected behavior or did I ran into a bug?

If you need more information, let me know. **Thank you** for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the composition API,
`this` is undefined in `script setup`.
See: https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#basic-usage

> setup() itself does not have access to the component instance - this will have a value of undefined inside setup()

Also since `user` is a computed function you always need to use `.value` when accessing it in the script, in the template you can omit the `.value`

Comment: Thanks, and I get that. But why is this.* working when I run "npm run dev"?